# How to select element whose sibling has text "X" in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, xml, dom

The xml content is like this:

```
<LinkSetDb>
 <DbTo>gds</DbTo>
 <LinkName>pubmed_gds</LinkName>
 <Link><Id>200028789</Id></Link>
 <Link><Id>200028788</Id></Link>
 <Link><Id>200028305</Id></Link>
 </LinkSetDb>
<LinkSetDb>
 <DbTo>not need</DbTo>
 <LinkName>not needed</LinkName>
 <Link><Id>1</Id></Link>
 <Link><Id>2</Id></Link>
 <Link><Id>3</Id></Link>
</LinkSetDb>
```

What I need is to get the `Link` elements who are (1) the children of `LinkSetDb` (2) has sibling `DbTo` whose content is `gds`. 
(The result would be these three nodes:

```
  <Link><Id>200028789</Id></Link>
  <Link><Id>200028788</Id></Link>
  <Link><Id>200028305</Id></Link>
```

)
I did some google and tried `$("LinkSetDb:contains('gds') Link)` but it doesn't work.. Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `~`, the [Next Siblings Selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/) `$("prev ~ siblings")`:

> > Selects all sibling elements that follow after the "prev" element, have the same parent, and match the filtering "siblings" selector.

More specific to your case:

```
$("LinkSetDb DbTo:contains('gds') ~ Link")
```